# window.open javascript sem a URL

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando abrir uma nova janela em javascript, mas sem a URL... ja tentei algumas formas e nada... alguém já conseguiu remover ela? Segue o meu código de teste inicial abaixo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to open an about:blank page in a new browser window that is 200px wide and 100px tall.</p>

<button onclick="popupwindow()">Try it</button>

<script>
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
 var w = 200;
        var h = 200;
        var left = Number((screen.width/2)-(w/2));
        var tops = Number((screen.height/2)-(h/2));

   return window.open('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/', '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+tops+', left='+left);
   //return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aqui deu certo: http://jsfiddle.net/8boju236/

Comment: Seu navegador não está bloqueando popup? Esse é seu código final?

Comment: Eu testei em alguns navegadores e nada... o código funciona só não esconde ou remove a URL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não pode esconder a barra de endereços nos navegadores modernos.

Isto é um recurso de segurança dos navegadores modernos e não existe nenhuma forma de ser contornada com `javascript` ou `HTML`.

Imagine que sem isso sites poderiam imitar popups de outros sites para tentar roubar senhas, por exemplo fingindo permitir logar no site usando o login do facebook, porém em vez de usar a API do facebook para mostrar o popup ele mostra um popup falso que imita o original.

Se você não quer mostrar a barra de endereço eu diria que a única alternativa é usar algum tipo de `modal` dentro da página e exibir o conteúdo do popup em um `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

Boa Noite!

Seu código está correto, efetuei testes com os seguintes navegadores.

- Mozilla Firefox Versão 37.0.2
- Google Chrome Versão 44.0.2403.155 m
- Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0

Sei que não devo pedir esclarecimentos na resposta mas no momento não posso comentar seu post, então gostaria de saber se esse é seu código final, e qual navegador está utilizando.

Comment: Eu atualizei para a ultima versão... o b.o que preciso remover a barra de navegação...

Comment: Compreendo, agora entendi a pergunta, nunca consegui esconter o endereco, você esta tentando fazer seu html parecer mais com um app nativo?

Comment: isso mesmo, mas vi que isso seria um recurso de segurança... para isso eu usei o dialog do bootstrap.